# How do I make a website run a perl CGI script without including the script name in the URL?

Tags: perl, url, cgi

When a user goes to 'http://www.mydomain.com/' currently index.html is returned.  Instead, I would like to run a CGI script.  How do I do that?

Comment: It depends on your HTTP server (e.g. IIS and Apache have completely different approaches to the issue).

Comment: Hint: tell us what software your web server uses

Comment: I am currently using Apache in a virtualized hosting environment.  Once I move to a dedicated server I am likely to explore other servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Apache you can add something like this to your VirtualHost config:

```
DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html index.htm
```

This would cause the web server to look for index.cgi first and then fall back to index.html and then index.htm  That's one way of doing it and, of course, you'd need to make sure your script is named index.cgi (or whatever default name you'd like to go with.  More info can be found [in the Apache docs for mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html)